# Perl, Compare and calculate the occurance of intersection between 2 arrays.

Tags: perl

assume the following situations:

I have two arrays: array1 and array2; both holding very large number of elements inside. There can be intersection element between these two arrays and inside each array, the elements can be either unique or duplicated. Now that I want to calculate the number of occurance for all those intersection elements. I know that I can use nested loop to traverse and compare each element inside both array, but see, since each of them is holding a large number of elements, the run speed is going to be terrible. I need to run this program frequently, so is there any faster way to achieve same purpose? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if a given value appears twice in array1 and three times in array2, how many intersections does that count as?

Comment: are the array values sorted?  how large is "very large"? millions?

Comment: sorry I did not make my situation clear enough. The case should be like: elements in array1 is unique, and each one of them might be shown up in array2, elements in array2 can be unique or duplicate. Now I want to calculate the number of occurance of elements from array1 that appeared in array2. Yes the size of array is like 10000+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need using nested loop. Just one `for` loop is enough to solve your problem. Below is the example but i not sure how you want to pass the array into scripts so i just put as `your array1`.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $i = 0;
my @array1 = "your array1";
my @array2 = "your array2";

for($i=0;$i<=$#array1;$i++){
    my $element_in_array1 = $array1[$i];
    my @occurrence = grep=/$element_in_array1/, @array2;
    print " This element $element_in_array1 occur in array2 %d time\n", scalar(@occurence);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and that's quite intuitive. Never realized "grep" can be used in same manner in Perl. Still a lot to learn. Anyway this should solve my doubts. Let me try out how much run time I can save.